# WinRT XAML Textbox, SelectionStart and CR/LF

Tags: c#, string, xaml, textbox, windows-store-apps

I am using a simple multiline `TextBox` in one of my `Windows Store Apps` and I would like to enable use of `tab` to indent the text.

Since WinRT doesn't have the XAML `AcceptsTab` property on the `TextBox` I figured I'd have to handle it per hand when I detect the Tab keystroke.

**The problem is: `\r\n` seems to be handled as one character instead of two by the SelectionStart property and I don't get the real `char` position.**

The only idea I have right now is to normalize the `SelectionStart` by parsing the text and adding 1 to the `SelectionStart` for each of the `\r\n` occurences I see before the caret.

```
public static class TextBoxExtension
{
    public static int GetNormalizedSelectionStart(this TextBox textBox)
    {
        int occurences = 0;
        string source = textBox.Text;

        for (var index = 0; index < textBox.SelectionStart + occurences ; index++)
        {
            if (source[index] == '\r' && source[index + 1] == '\n')
                occurences++;
        }
        return textBox.SelectionStart + occurences;
    }
}
```

Finally the `SelectionStart` gets reseted to 0 after the manipulation, so I have to set it back to the correct position, this time using the non normalized position. Here's the caller:

```
if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Tab)
{
    int cursorIndex = MainTextBox.SelectionStart;
    int cursorIndexNormalized = MainTextBox.GetNormalizedSelectionStart();
    MainTextBox.Text = MainTextBox.Text.Insert(cursorIndexNormalized, "\t");
    MainTextBox.SelectionStart = cursorIndex + 1;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

It works but... have I reinvented that round thing again? Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Even though the question is old you should verify the answer as answering the needs you had or not for future users to see and to take the question out of the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to do a "Ctrl + Tab" to actually insert a tab in your textbox. Therefor all you have to do is something like this

```
TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
      {
          e.Handled = true;
          SendKeys(^{TAB});
      }
}
```

The `^` represents the `CTRL` key and the `TAB` your tab key. Using this combination you are able to use Tab normally in your application